# Windows Service can't load DLLs on release

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

This is a little weird and I've been racking my brain for the past week trying to figure this out.

I have a windows service that's going to serve as a new site launcher (internal tool). I have 5 projects in the solution:

- IISWrapper (.NET Standard 2.0)
- SiteLauncher (this is the service project) (.NET Framework 4.7)
- SiteLauncher.Debug (console app for debugging web interface) (.NET Framework 4.7)
- SiteLauncher.Actions (.NET Framework 4.7)
- SiteLauncher.WebUI (.NET Framework 4.7)

I'm using NancyFx self hosting as the web interface. All 5 projects are built with the x86 architecture set in Visual Studio. IISWrapper references Micorosft.Web.Administration, which is .NET Core, so it has to be .NET Standard for the service to use it.

This all works. As long as the service is built in debug. If I switch it to Release, I get errors like this when it tries to interact with IIS:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

```
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateAdminManager[TClass,TInterface](WebConfigurationMap webConfigMap, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean isRedirectionConfig)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateWritableAdminManager(WebConfigurationMap webConfigMap, String configPathToEdit, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean isRedirectionConfig)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateConfiguration(WebConfigurationMap configMap, String configPathToEdit, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean isRedirectionConfig)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration(String rawConfigurationPath, String cacheKey, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean isRedirectionConfig)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.ApplicationPoolsSectionCreator()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_ApplicationPoolsSection()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.ApplicationPoolCollectionCreator()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_ApplicationPools()
at IISWrapper.IISManager.CreateAppPool(String appPoolName, String userName, String password, Int64 memoryLimit)
at SiteLauncher.Actions.NewSiteSetup.SetUpSite(SiteCreatedEventArgs ev) in C:\Websites\manwaringweb\SiteLauncher\SiteLauncher.Actions\NewSiteSetup.cs:line 303
at SiteLauncher.Actions.NewSiteSetup.SvnUpdate_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Websites\manwaringweb\SiteLauncher\SiteLauncher.Actions\NewSiteSetup.cs:line 53
```

NewSiteSetup.cs line 303 is the `using` statement:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:g}: Creating website...");
using (IISManager manager = new IISManager())
{
    manager.CreateAppPool(ev.Site.DomainName, ev.DbName, userPass);
    Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\inetpub\{ev.Site.DomainName}");
    manager.CreateWebsite(ev.Site.DomainName, $@"C:\inetpub\{ev.Site.DomainName}");
}
```

The `IISManager.CreateAppPool` method:

```
public void CreateAppPool(string appPoolName, string userName, string password, long memoryLimit = 200000)
{
    ApplicationPool pool = _manager.ApplicationPools.Add(appPoolName);
    pool.Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true;
    pool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.PrivateMemory = memoryLimit;
    pool.Cpu.Action = ProcessorAction.NoAction;
    pool.Cpu.Limit = 30000;
    pool.Failure.RapidFailProtectionMaxCrashes = 10;
    pool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;
    pool.ProcessModel.UserName = userName;
    pool.ProcessModel.Password = password;
    pool.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;

    _manager.CommitChanges();
}
```

I have verified that this library exists in the output folder. Oddly enough, I get this on the console app project in release as well. I don't know what the difference is.

I've verified that the same packages are installed in the service and the console app. Both seem to work in debug mode but fail in release mode.

Service Class:

```cs
public partial class SiteLauncher : ServiceBase
{
    NancyHost _host;

    public SiteLauncher()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _host = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:9664"));
        _host.Start();

        WebEvents events = new WebEvents();
        events.SiteCreated += Events_SiteCreated;
        Bootstrapper.webEvents = events;
    }

    private void Events_SiteCreated(object sender, SiteCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewSiteSetup.Initialize(e);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _host.Stop();
    }
}
```

Console app Program.cs:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var nancyHost = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:9664"));
        nancyHost.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Web server running on http://localtest.me:9664...");

        WebEvents events = new WebEvents();
        events.SiteCreated += Events_SiteCreated;
        Bootstrapper.webEvents = events;


        Console.ReadLine();
        nancyHost.Stop();
    }

    private static void Events_SiteCreated(object sender, SiteCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:g}: Site {e.Site.DomainName} (ID: {e.Site.Id}) Created, with Repo: {e.Repository}");

        NewSiteSetup.Initialize(e);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try removing assembly references which are not in use?

Comment: Yes, I went through all of the projects and made sure I was only referencing the assemblies I needed.

Comment: Does it have to do anything with #ifdebug macro?

Comment: I am using `#if !DEBUG` for one section to determine which IP address to use for a connection string. But it gets past that just fine.

Comment: One thing you can try is close the solution, delete .suo file and reopen solution then try?

Comment: I just tried it. I didn't really expect it to work since I stick it on the server to run as a service, but I figured might as well give it a try. No dice. Same error.

Comment: I edited to include more information from the error message.

Comment: The NuGet version of `Microsoft.Web.Administration` is designed for the IIS administration REST API. Please use the version shipped with local IIS instead.

Comment: @LexLi Could you write that as an answer and perhaps explain why that would make it fail? I can't find any documentation that says not to use NuGet on the same machine that has IIS installed. And this whole thing works in debug build so what makes the release build different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NuGet version of Microsoft.Web.Administration is designed for the IIS administration REST API. Please use the version shipped with local IIS instead.

More information can be found in [my blog post](https://blog.lextudio.com/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know-b82f2c974da6).

Comment: Thanks. As I said, nothing like that came up in my earlier searches. This is helpful.